# On button Click call a js file and parse it

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, openlayers

I have a task were I need to call through ajax, a *.KML file and parse it to put the points on the open layer map. This is so far what I managed to do, there are no errors and it just refresh the page on button click. Could you please guide me through what I am doing wrong?

```js
 $('#get-myData').click(function() {

   $.ajax({
     url: 'C:\..\kmlFile\2015-05-11_141102_imt2015.kml',
     dataType: 'html',
     success: function(data) {
       console.log(data);
       var Google = new google.maps.LatLng(37.42228990140251, -122.0822035425683);
       var mapOptions = {
         zoom: 18,
         center: Google
       }

       var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
       var geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({
         map: map
       });

       geoXml.parseKmlString(date);

       ctaLayer.setMap(map);
       console.log(data);

     }
   });
 }); < /script>
```

```html
<body>
<form runat="server">
  <input id="get-myData" type="submit" value="Click Me" />
</form>

</body>
```

As you might have noticed I am brining the file from a local folder.

Comment: Is `#get-myData` in a form?

Comment: yes I removed it since i got a large bulk of code in the page

Answer (score 3):

> it just refresh the page on button click.

You can use `preventDefault()` to stop the page refresh.

```
 $('#get-myData').click(function(ev) {//ev is the event
   ev.preventDefault();//Prevent default action
   .....
```

**Edit**

You can also prevent the refresh by changing your `button` from `type=submit` to type `button`.

```
<input id="get-myData" type="button" value="Click Me" />
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

One more solution is to `return false` like

```
 $('#get-myData').click(function() {

   $.ajax({
     url: 'C:\..\kmlFile\2015-05-11_141102_imt2015.kml',
     dataType: 'html',
     success: function(data) {
       console.log(data);
       var Google = new google.maps.LatLng(37.42228990140251, -122.0822035425683);
       var mapOptions = {
         zoom: 18,
         center: Google
       }

       var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
       var geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({
         map: map
       });

       geoXml.parseKmlString(date);

       ctaLayer.setMap(map);
       console.log(data);

     }
   });
   return false; //HERE
 });
```

However, I feel `preventDefault` is better than `return false` as it better shows your intention.

Comment: Although the suggestion is solid, I do wonder...: submit *what* (since the button isn't inside a form, whereto should it POST/GET)? Also, ending the `onclick` function with `return false` should then also fix the problem.. Just curious. EDIT: lol my comment and your edit crossed eachother, indeed, preventDefault is in that same line of thought. But I still wonder.. submit *what*.

Comment: @GitaarLAB. We can't say if the button is inside a form or not as I don't think OP gave his full HTML markup. I guess OP can clarify this. But since he said the `page refresh`, I suspect that the button is inside a form. I was also not sure, thats why changed the answer a bit ;)

Comment: Ah, the op just clarified that (it's in a form). Then there's indeed the solution: `return false` or `preventDefault` or changing the input-type from `submit` to `button`. +1 PS: feel free to add the other 2 options in your answer.

Comment: Done :D haha you made me laugh, yes its inside a form I have a big bulk of code... ok now the page is not refreshing